# Implementing an interface in classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class that implements a class **Bag**, which has room for an unlimited number of strings and which supports the methods in the interface. I have to implement following classes:

**Simplebag** (this class contains the strings in the order they have been added)
**BagWithoutRepetitions** (this class does the same as Simplebag with the addition that there are no duplicates)

My issue is that I've no idea how the set up of the classes would work, and how you refer to a class containing a method.

I have this so far, but it's not possible to test anything with it because I'm sure that I'm referencing to the classes incorrectly:

```
public interface Bag {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    class SimpleBag implements Bag {
        ArrayList<String> bag = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    }
```

This is the interface

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public interface Bag {


/** Add the string "str" to the strings in the bag as the last 
 * element. It str was added then the method returns "true" and
 * "false" otherwise.
 * @param str
 * @return true iff succesfully added
 */
public  boolean addString(String str);

/** Removes all ocurrences of "str" from the bag.
 * If "str" occurred at least once in the bag then the method
 * returns "true" and "false" otherwise.
 * @param str
 * @return true iff str occured at least once
 */
public boolean removeAllOccurrences(String str);

/** Returns the string which currently is at the position given
 * by "index". In case the operation cannot be conducted, the 
 * method returns "null".
 * @param index
 * @return string at index or null
 */
public  String getString(int index);

/** returns the number of elements currently in the bag.
 *  Indexing starts with 0.
 * 
 * @return number of elements in the bag
 */
public  int noOfElements();
}
```

How do I go on from here?

Comment: It's not clear to me *why* you've got the method and the class within your interface - or what you want your `main` method to do. Also, your interface doesn't have any methods - think about what you want to be able to do with any `Bag` instance.

Comment: I'm sure your assignment provides the code for the `Bag` interface. As a start, please [edit] your question and post it. I'm also sure that your task is to write two classes where each one implements interface `Bag`. The name of these classes are `SimpleBag` and `BagWithoutRepetitions`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Abra Yes you've understood it correctly, and I've also uploaded the interface. My issue here is not writing the code for each of the methods but how I implement the interface Bag in each of the classes (there are more than the two classes mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleBag` needs to be a separate class.

```java
public class SimpleBag implements Bag {
}
```

Class `SimpleBag` needs to contain all the methods that appear in `Bag`.
Here is an incomplete skeleton.

```java
public class SimpleBag implements Bag {
    public boolean addString(String str) {
        // TODO: Complete.
        return false; // To make sure this code compiles.
    }

    public boolean removeAllOccurrences(String str) {
        // TODO: Complete.
        return false; // To make sure this code compiles.
    }

    public String getString(int index) {
        // TODO: Complete.
        return null; // To make sure this code compiles.
    }

    public int noOfElements() {
        // TODO: Complete.
        return 0; // To make sure this code compiles.
    }
}
```

Similarly create another class `BagWithoutRepetitions` that also contains all the methods from interface `Bag`. Here is an even more minimal skeleton.

```java
public class BagWithoutRepetitions implements Bag {
}
```

Then you can write another class to test your `SimpleBag` (and `BagWithoutRepetitions`) class.
Here is a skeleton for that tester class.

```java
public class BagTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bag bag = new SimpleBag();
        bag.addString("George");
        bag.addString("Best");
        bag.addString("Northern");
        bag.addString("Ireland");
        bag.addString("Manchester");
        bag.addString("United");
        int count = bag.noOfElements();
        System.out.printf("Bag contains %d elements.%n", count);
    }
}
```

Try to complete the above skeletons. Edit your question and add the code you will write and indicate where you are having difficulty.

Good luck!